# Partial view works on local PC but not when published

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've have a folder titled "About" with three .cshtml files in it. The partial views work correctly on my local PC but when I send the build to the server it comes back with an error.

> @Html.Partial("_1")
>
> @Html.Partial("_2")
>
> @Html.Partial("_3")

It loads fine on my local computer but when I publish it to the server I get these errors:

> The partial view '_1.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

But I know for a fact the _1.cshtml file is there. Maybe I have different versions of MVC or something?

Comment: is it possible to post the error screenshot ?

Comment: can you navigate directly to the partial?  wondering if rights are setup on that folder or if the path to the folder is the same on the server as local

Comment: I figured it out. I was checking in my changes but not publishing them. I didn't know I had to do both.